# Disable CSS animation on hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I currently have a div class `black` with a flash animation on it, on hover it changes to green.

`black` has an `::after` state with the animation on it.

Unfortunately on hover state the animation is still applied, how do i get the hover state stay as a static colour without having the animation effect it?

Here's the code example: https://jsfiddle.net/zje0pb8v/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the css psuedo-class `:not()` with `:hover`

Updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zje0pb8v/3/

```
.black:not(:hover)::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    content: "";
    width: 120px;
    height: 205px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-animation: flash3 steps(1, end) 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flash3 steps(1, end) 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: flash3 steps(1, end) 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: flash3 steps(1, end) 2s infinite;
    animation: flash3 steps(1, end) 2s infinite;
}
```